# Como disparar un evento de un formulario en otro

Tags: c#, windows-forms, eventos

Estoy trabajando con 2 formularios, de los cuales, el primero hace de caja flotante para recoger datos que son ingresados por el usuario. Una vez ingresados los datos, el usuario pulsa el botón `Aplicar` para enviar los datos recogidos al segundo formulario, quiero que se dispare un evento en la clase del segundo.

En el primer formulario tengo esto:

```
    public event EventHandler Aplicar;

    public void InvocarAplicar()
    {
        this.Aplicar?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void Aplicar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvocarAplicar();  
    }
```

Un evento `Aplicar` que quiero que se dispare en la clase del segundo formulario:

```
private Form1 form1 = new Form1();

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    form1.Aplicar += (s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Funciona");
    };
}
```

El problema es que no funciona, cuando hago click en el boton `Aplicar` del primero, el `MessageBox` que esta en la clase del segundo no se muestra.

Si lo hago asi:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    form1.Aplicar += (s, e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Funciona");
    };
    form1.InvocarAplicar(); //Llamando diretamente
}
```

Entonces sí funciona, pero yo necesito que el `MessageBox` que esta en la clase de `Form2` solo se muestre cuando se hace click en el boton `Aplicar` de `Form1`.

Lo que necesito es disparar un evento en otro formulario desde un boton.

Alguien puede decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

**Actualización:**

> Se han fijado en que si se llama por ejemplo a `Form1.Paint` o `Form1.Disposing` o cualquier evento predefinido, desde `Form2`, este se ejecutará?
>
> Debería existir una forma de que pasara lo mismo con los eventos que definimos nosotros mismos.

Comment: el form1 lo muestras desde dentro del form2?

Comment: Podrias explicar mejor que te pasa? porque asi como esta, no se entiende si el problema es que no podes disparar el evento, o que queres suscribirte despeus, o que simplemente estas llamando al messagabox del formulario equivocado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: Como se ha solucionado en los comentarios de esta respuesta, la actualizo para que tenga mas visibilidad. Tal y como le indicamos el compañero @Pikoh y un servidor, al final el error se encuentra en esta línea:

```
private Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

Al crear una nueva instancia del `Form1` en vez de utilizar la ya existente estamos creando un nuevo formulario distinto al que ya teníamos, por lo tanto el evento `Aplicar` **nunca será alcanzado** desde el Form2.

Para solucionar esto, @Pikoh recomienda pasar como parámetro la instancia del Form1 al Form2 y asignar el Form1 en el constructor:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
```

Donde `this` es la referencia actual del `Form1` que estamos utilizando.

Comment: Veo innecesario suscribirse al evento del form1 desde el form2 cuando sencillamente puedes invocar al método del form2 desde el form1. El OP lo está haciendo al contrario. Cierto es que no está muy bien explicado y puedo estar entendiendo algo que no es jeje

Comment: @Pikoh Oh, si, fue mi error

Comment: @Pikoh Por cierto,  he editado mi post, por favor revisalo

Comment: @Corpex Gracias Corpex, pero realmente esto ya lo sabia, y si, lo hice, sin embargo realmente tiene que ser un evento y no un método, pero +1 de todas formas

Comment: @Corpex He actualizado mi post, por favor, revisa la últia parte

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán tu codigo es correcto, yo lo he probado y funciona. Por eso, como he comentado antes, me temo que el problema es que creas `private Form1 form1 = new Form1();`, con lo que form1 no es tu formulario 1, sino una nueva instancia del formulario. Por eso no se dispara el evento

Comment: @Pikoh Bueno, entonces tendria que hacer una referencia directa al Form1 creando una propiedad pública y asignadola a la clase del Form1?

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán yo lo que haría sería pasar en el constructor del formulario 2 la instancia del formulario1. Algo como `Form2= new Form2(this);`

Comment: @Pikoh Permiteme probar, eso puede funcionar

Comment: @Pikoh Efectivamente funciona, pero el problema es que en mi codigo estos formularios se disposean cuando ya no se necesitan, por lo que pasar la la instancia de la clase actual en el constructor no funcionaria en este caso

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán en ese caso, deberás replantear la manera que estás llamando de unos formularios a otros. Podrías encontrar la instancia del formulario usando la colección `Application.OpenForms.OfType<tipodetuformulario>`, aunque no es una manera muy limpia de hacerlo. Pero esa pregunta ya es demasiado extensa para responderla aqui. Al menos, ya sabes cual era el problema con tu código :)

Comment: Me he tomado la molestia de actualizar la respuesta indicando lo hablado en estos comentarios para así darle mas visibilidad y así facilitárselo a otros compañeros. Como comenta el compañero Pikoh, creo que la siguiente parte se aleja del problema inicial y por tanto aplica a otra Pregunta distinta.